# JPA - @JoinColumn @ManyToOne to Class composed by PkClass

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, join

I'm trying to implement an internationalization class to translate contents from database.

I have these tables:

[image: database mapping]

And I have theses classes:

**ProductModel:**

```
public class ProductModel implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idproduct_model")
private Integer idproductModel;

@Size(max = 80, message = "El campo nombre esta vacio")
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Size(max = 45, message = "El campo referencia esta vacio")
@Column(name = "productSuppReference")
private String productSuppReference;

    ...
```

**Language:**

```
public class LanguageCountry implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_language")
private Integer idLanguage;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "languageCountry1")
private List<ProductModelI18n> productModelI18nList;

 ...
```

**ProductModelI18n:**

```
public class ProductModelI18n implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected ProductModelI18nPK productModelI18nPK;

@Size(max = 80)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Lob
@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Size(max = 800)
@Column(name = "description2")
private String description2;

@JoinColumn(name = "language_country", referencedColumnName = "id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private LanguageCountry languageCountry1;
```

**ProductModelI18nPK:**

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductModelI18nPK implements Serializable {

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "product_model")
private int productModel;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "language_country")
private int languageCountry;
```

I have problems because I need a double PK in a ProductModelI18n table to get a manytomany relation between productmodel and languageCountry and now I don't know how to do a join table in productModel.

I need an ArrayList/Map in ProductModel class.

Thank you in advance!

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Sorry my bad I missed the fact that you have extra columns in the Join table, so just need to decompose the `ManyToMany` association between `ProductModel` and `LanguageCountry` into two `OneToMany` associations.

Your code should look like:

**in `ProductModel` class:**

```
@OneToMany
private List<ProductModelI18n> ProductLanguages;
```

**In `LanguageCountry` class:**

```
@OneToMany
private List<ProductModelI18n> ProductLanguages;
```

**And in your ProductModelI18n class:**

Keep all the other fields including the IdPK and add the following declarations.

```
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="productModel", referencedColumnName="idproductModel")
private ProductModel productModels ;
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="languageCountry", referencedColumnName="idLanguage")
private LanguageCountry LanguageCountries;
```

**Note:**

Make sure you include all the getters and setters.

---

There's no need to create the class `ProductModelI18n` to make a `ManyToMany` relation between `productmodel` and `languageCountry`.

You only need two `Collections` in these two classes mapped with `@ManyToMany` annotation where in one of the two sides you define a `@JoinTable` here's the code you need:

**In `ProductModel` class:**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="ProductModelI18n",
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="productModel", referencedColumnName="idproductModel")},
  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="languageCountry", referencedColumnName="idLanguage")})
private List<LanguageCountry> languageCountries;
```

**And in your `LanguageCountry` class:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="languageCountries")
private List<ProductModel> productModels;
```

And you will get a Join table between the two tables as represented in the picture.

For further information you can take a look at:

- **[JPA 2 Tutorial – Relationships – Many To Many](http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2012/12/17/jpa-2-relationships-many-to-many/)**.
- **[Java Persistence/ManyToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany)**

Comment: The problems is that ProductModel has some products' features, like weight, price... On the other hand, ProductModelI18n has names, descriptions, comments, all data that can be translate. That's why I need that relation.